# VBScript to move files gets error "Expected statement"

Tags: windows, vbscript, move

I am writing a script to move files between directories. I copied and edited this script from another post:

```
MOVE C:\Users\evan\Downloads\*.mp3 C:\Users\evan\Music
```

and I run it from the CLI using

```
cscript test.vbs
```

I would expect it to work, but I get this message:

```
C:\Users\evan\test.vbs<1,8> Microsoft VBScript compiliation error: Expaected statement
```

Can someone please explain what this error message means or point out my mistake that causes the error message? Sorry for being such a noob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a batch file, but you are trying to invoke it as a VBScript. Rename your file to `.bat` and invoke it directly.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you. Can you tell me what makes it a batch file and not a VBScript?

Comment: I would vote you up, but I don't have the required 15 rep points. Sorry :(

Comment: The fact that you are using a command that belongs in a batch file, not in a VBScript. VBScript would involve using `FileSystemObject`

Comment: Batch files use Windows command language : http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true